# How to pull from ECR Docker registry on EC2 instance using Terraform?

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, terraform

## The problem

I want to make a certain Docker image from my ECR repository present on an EC2 instance, using Terraform.

## What I did

### Permissions and credentials helper

I have configured permissions (so that instance profile role can log in and pull images) and installed credentials helper on the instance. I put `{"credsStore": "ecr-login"}` in `/home/ec2-user/.docker/config.json`. I can SSH into the instance and do `docker pull image:tag` - this works, no need to do `docker login`.

*I can also do the same using my local docker client by doing `docker -H ssh://ec2-user@instance-dns-name.com:22 pull image:tag` - the image gets pulled onto the instance.*
**EDIT:** Turns out that this command worked because I was *locally* authenticated to the registry. Without being locally authenticated it won't pull the image. Thanks, @ydaetskcoR.

### Terraform configuration

I was trying to do it in Terraform using Docker provider. Here's what I have:

```
provider "docker" {
  version = "~> 2.7"
  host = "ssh://ec2-user@${aws_instance.main.public_dns}:22"
}

data "docker_registry_image" "backend" {
  name = "image:tag"
}

resource "docker_image" "remote_backend" {
  name = data.docker_registry_image.backend.name
  pull_triggers = [data.docker_registry_image.backend.sha256_digest]
}
```

IIUC, this should pull the image onto the remote machine. However, Terraform exits with this error:

```
Error: Got error when attempting to fetch image version from registry: Bad credentials: 401 Unauthorized

  on swarm.tf line 1, in data "docker_registry_image" "backend":
   1: data "docker_registry_image" "backend" {
```

I verified that Terraform actually connects to the remote Docker host (I could create docker service) - it just won't authenticate to the registry.

I also tried defining config like this (not sure if this is a good approach since I want to use credentials helper on a remote machine, not my local one):

```
provider "docker" {
  version = "~> 2.7"
  host = "ssh://ec2-user@${aws_instance.main.public_dns}:22"
  registry_auth {
    address = local.docker_registry_url
    config_file_content = "{\"credsStore\": \"ecr-login\"}"
  }
}
```

But this in turn results in a following error:

```
Error: Error loading registry auth config: Error parsing docker registry config json: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type docker.dockerConfig
```

## The question

How can I make this work, so that an image is pulled on the remote machine, using credentials provided by `ecr-login` helper which runs on that machine?
Or maybe it's a bug of Docker Terraform provider?

Comment: This looks like you are using the remote Docker socket on the EC2 machine. I'm pretty sure that the credentials for registries is handled client side so that would mean you need to be authenticated on the machine where you are running that from (eg your laptop etc) instead of the EC2 instance that you refer to in the provider config.

Comment: Hm, you might be right... I checked again and it turns out that I was able to do `docker -H ... pull` because I was locally authenticated to the registry. Once I deleted authentication token, this command stopped working. Thank you!

Comment: Does the EC2 have to be already running or can the EC2 instance be replaced when a new image pull is required?

Comment: @FrancisEytanDortort I wouldn't be interested in a solution involving instance replacement. It would be an overkill. Thanks anyway.